# How to set dynamic URL parameters to a variable value with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, dynamic-routing

I looked quite a bit online for this but didnt seem to find the right answer to my question.
How do I change a part of my URL to a value from for example UserInput.

I am using react-router-dom v6 and react 18.2

I tried to use UseParams but it didnt work as wished.
Also I tried redirect and useHistory but it didnt lead to the wished result, perhaps i used them wrong in my scenario

This is what i have so far:

App.js

```
let persID = useContext(NumContext); // i use this since the Original value lays in another Script

return (


<Link to="/schedule/mySchedule/:persID" ><p className="NavText">My Timetable</p></Link> {/* persID is the dynamic URL part that should be replaced with a value out of varaible */}


<Route path="/schedule/mySchedule/:persID" element={<MySchedule />} />


)
```

What i want is that if the value of the varable is 2 it leads to the URL /schedule/mySchedule/2

I've seen people do this but they had to replace the part of the dynamic route manually

I am Thankful for any advice or leads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i want is that if the value of the varable is 2 it leads to the URL /schedule/mySchedule/2

You could use *template literal* to include the `persID` param within the *link*.

```
<Link to={`/schedule/mySchedule/${persID}`} />
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thank you, i guess it was just as simple as that

Comment: i absolutly will :D thank you